# Add the new regression line but keep the regression lines from previous runs in R

Tags: r, layout, plot, bootstrapping, par

## Background

I have a function called `TPN` (***R code is below the picture***). When you run this function, it produces two plots (**see picture below**). The bottom-row plot samples from the top-row plot and then **adds** **a red regression line.** Each time you run the `TPN` function, the **bottom-row plot produces a new red-colored regression line**.

### Question

In the **bottom-row plot**, I was wondering if there is a way I could KEEP the regression lines from previous runs each time I run the `TPN` function (**see picture below**)?

That is, each time that I run a new `TPN` function the regression line from a previous run is kept in its place (*probably in a color other than "red" for distinction purposes*), and the **new regression line is just added to he bottom-row plot?**

[image]

```
############## Input Values #################
 TPN = function(      each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                      sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                      predict.range = 10:0, 
                      sub.pop.sd = .75,
                      n.sample = 2   ) {
#############################################
 par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

 m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
 set.seed(2460986)
 Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

 y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
 set.seed(NULL)
 x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

 plot(x, y, ylim = range(y)) ## Top-Row Plot


  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                 x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

     x = sample$x  ;  y = sample$y

     plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))  #### BOTTOM-ROW PLOT

     abline(lm(y ~ x), col = 'red') # Regression Line

      }
      ## TEST HERE:
      TPN()
```

Answer (score 3):

It ain't that easy. I made another function and edit the first one as well.

To summarize what I have done:

I made the first function to set `par(new = TRUE)` at the end of it. Also, set the color for points in the bottom row plot to be white only for formatting. You can get rid of `col = 'white', bg = 'white'` if you wish.

Then, in the second function top row plot does not get plotted and yaxis won't be added to the bottom row plot from each "test".

Look below:

```
############## Input Values #################
TPN = function(      each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                     sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                     predict.range = 10:0, 
                     sub.pop.sd = .75,
                     n.sample = 2   ) {
  #############################################
  par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

  m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
  set.seed(2460986)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  set.seed(NULL)
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  par(new = FALSE)
  plot(x, y, ylim = range(y)) ## Top-Row Plot


  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                       x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

  x = sample$x  ;  y = sample$y

  plot(x, y, ylim = range(y), col = 'white', bg = 'white')  #### BOTTOM-ROW PLOT
  abline(lm(y ~ x), col = 'red') # Regression Line
  par(new = TRUE)
}
```

The second one does not plot the top row one:

```
############## Input Values #################
TPN2 = function(      each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                     sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                     predict.range = 10:0, 
                     sub.pop.sd = .75,
                     n.sample = 2   ) {
  #############################################
  par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

  m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
  set.seed(2460986)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  set.seed(NULL)
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  #par(new = FALSE)                           #comment-out
  #plot(x, y, ylim = range(y)) ##Top-Row Plot #comment-out


  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                       x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

  x = sample$x  ;  y = sample$y

  plot(x, y, ylim = range(y), axes = FALSE,  col = 'white', bg = 'white') ##BOTTOM-ROW PLOT
  abline(lm(y ~ x), col = 'blue') # Regression Line
  par(new = TRUE)
}
```

Then your test would be like this:

```
## TEST HERE:
TPN()

TPN2()
TPN2()
TPN2()
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: @user138773 if you haven't had two plots (layout) that'd be much easier but now, this is the way I would do it, unless I wanna rewrite it and change your approach completely.

Comment: @user138773 https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/146285.html

Comment: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2852_379274d7c5734f979e106dcf019ec46c.html

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do what you want is to change your *main effect* (currently none) to return an **accumulation of previous regressions** and your *side effect* (plotting) to **loop through these previous regressions** (in blue) in addition to the current one (in red).

Another tip: you can use the `abline(reg=lm(y~x))` argument and just accumulate the `lm` objects in a list.  It's not necessary to store coefficients and intercepts separately as suggested in the other answer.  Keeping the `lm` objects is also a good idea in case you want to go back and look at average R-squared, etc. -- you couldn't do that using only the coefficients.

Your new function could look like:

```
TPN.accum <- function(  each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                        sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                        predict.range = 10:0, 
                        sub.pop.sd = .75,
                        n.sample = 2,
                        lm.history = list() # the accumulator
                       ){
  par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )
  m <- matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
  set.seed(2460986)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  set.seed(NULL)
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))               ### Top-Row Plot

  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                       x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

  x <- sample$x  ;  y <- sample$y

  lm.current <- lm(y~x)                     # the current regression

  plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))               ### Bottom-Row Plot

  abline(reg = lm.current, col = 'red')     # plot current regression (red)
  for( i in seq_along(lm.history) ){
    abline(reg=lm.history[[i]], col='blue') # plot any previous regressions (blue)
  }
  return(c(lm.history, list(lm.current)))   # append current regression to accumulator
}
```

To initialize it and then run it repeatedly, just do something like:

```
tpn.history <- TPN.accum()
for (i in 1:5) tpn.history <- TPN.accum(lm.history=tpn.history)
```

And your output will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose two possibilities:

1. Use `par(mfg)` to define on which panel to draw, so that you can add new points or lines on any of the two. For the color, I propose to add options saying if this is the first plot or the last plot of the series.
2. Store the coefficients of the abline to be used on other plots.

## Use `par(mfg)`

I used some transparent color so that we do not see all superimposition of each iteration. Depending on what you want to achieve, you can modify this.

```
############## Input Values #################
TPN <- function(each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                predict.range = 10:0, 
                sub.pop.sd = .75,
                n.sample = 2,   
                plot = TRUE,
                first = FALSE,
                last = FALSE) {
  #############################################

  if (plot & first) {
    plot.new()
    m <- matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
    par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )
  }

  set.seed(2460986)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  set.seed(NULL)
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  if (plot) {
    par(mfg = c(1,1)) ## Top-Row Plot  
    if (first) {
      plot(x, y, ylim = range(y), col = "transparent")
    } else if (last) {
      plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))     
    }
  }

  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                       x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

  x = sample$x  ;  y = sample$y

  if (plot) {
    par(mfg = c(2,1))   #### BOTTOM-ROW PLOT
    if (first) {
      plot(x, y, ylim = range(y), col = "transparent")
    }
    if (last) {
      points(x, y)
    }
    abline(lm(y ~ x), col = c('blue', 'red')[(last) + 1]) # Regression Line
  }
}
## TEST HERE:
n <- 10
for (i in 1:n) {
  TPN(first = ifelse(i == 1, TRUE, FALSE), last = ifelse(i == n, TRUE, FALSE))
}
```

## Store the abline coefficients

There is no need of transparent color here because, a new plot is created for each iteration.

```
############## Input Values #################
TPN <- function(each.sub.pop.n = 150, 
                sub.pop.means = 20:10, 
                predict.range = 10:0, 
                sub.pop.sd = .75,
                n.sample = 2,   
                plot = TRUE,
                coefs = FALSE,
                coefsup = NULL) {
  #############################################
  if (plot) {
    m <- matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 )
    layout(m)
    par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )
  }

  set.seed(2460986)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  set.seed(NULL)
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  if (plot) {
    plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))
  }

  sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
  sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                       x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))

  x = sample$x  ;  y = sample$y

  if (plot) {
    plot(x, y, ylim = range(y))
    # Add the previous lines if exists
    if (!is.null(coefsup)) {
      apply(coefsup, 1, function(x) abline(a = x[1], b = x[2], col = "blue")) 
    }
    abline(lm(y ~ x), col = 'red') # Regression Line
  }
  if (coefs) {return(coef(lm(y ~ x)))}
}
# TEST with coefs
n <- 10
coefsup <- NULL
for (i in 1:n) {
  coefsup <- rbind(coefsup, TPN(coefs = TRUE, coefsup = coefsup))
}
```

In both cases, the output is what you expect:
[image: Multiple draw on biplots]

Comment: Would you add the outputs (plots) to your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry for "harassing" you but you need to get rid of `xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"` in your first solution if you want to present both ones in one plot. Actually, they should not be there in the first place. What is a plot without any scale?

Comment: Ok, but the figure is the same as we play with classical plots. I think there is no real best answer. It depends what you want to achieve after that. Is this only to look at output will a model is running in case you do not have to save all outputs, or do you want to be able to use the outputs of each iteration, in case you can save part or all the outputs.

Comment: That I cannot say for sure as I am not the OP. But based on our conversation (that unfortunately s/he deleted the comments) I think this is only for some visualization purposes.